# Change Div background when input is clicked - How?

Tags: html, input

Does anyone know how to the change the background of a DIV when the a `<input>` is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jquery:

```
$('#input_id').click(function() {
  $('#div_id').css('background-image','url')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("my_input_id");

input.onclick = function ()
{
    document.getElementById("my_div").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```